# pymongo is not leveraging my compound index

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection with over 2 million records. I have created an index on two columns `provider` and `provider_product_id`

When I find a particular record using both the columns, it fetches in milliseconds. However, when I am querying (same query) using pymongo, its taking ages and still not giving result. I am not even able to get the result of explain. Tried hint but still no luck. Any idea if I am missing something general ?

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo in the pymongo query

```
 mongo_product = MongoProduct.find_one({"provider": "my_provider"," provider_product_id": "itmdz6ydeusgqczh"})
```

There is an extra space in provider_product_id that was causing the issue. Sorry for posting this. My bad